# Enabling x number of prepopulated form array controls with Angular Reactive Form

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

Creating an application with Angular and Reactive forms builder.

[StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-prepopulate-dynamic-reactive-form-array-5cjchf?file=src/app/app.component.html)

The form is prepopulated and within the form I am using `form.array` to build up a dynamic list of controls based on the data. I have disabled the fields as I want my form to be read-only initially. I have a button that triggers `.enable` on the controls, however as the dynamic controls in the `form.array`, I am not sure how I can enable these without specifying all of the controls index value.

**ts file**

```
  public createForm() {
    this.service.getmodel().subscribe((response) => {
      this.model = response;

      this.form = this.fb.group({
        type: new FormControl({ value: null, disabled: !this.isOwner }),
        items: this.fb.array(
          this.model.items.map((x) =>
            this.buildFields(x)
          )
        ),
      });
    });
  }

  buildFields(x: any): FormGroup {
    return new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl({ value: x.name, disabled: !this.isOwner }),
      description: new FormControl({
        value: x.description,
        disabled: !this.isOwner,
      }),
      code: new FormControl({ value: x.code, disabled: !this.isOwner }),
    });
  }

  enable() {
    this.isOwner = true;
    const controls = ['type', 'items.description'];
    controls.map((x) => {
      this.form.get(x).enable({ onlySelf: true });
    });
  }
```

I am enabling the control "type" which enables a text input field, for the items in the form.array I have just added "items.description" - although I know this is incorrect as this value does not exist. It would be something like "items[0].description" but [0] could be any value determined by the length of the data.

**html file**

```
<div *ngIf="form">
  <form [formGroup]="form">
    <textarea
      formControlName="type"
      name="type"
      #type
      class="form-control"
      id="type"
      rows="6"
    ></textarea>
    <div formArrayName="items">
      <div
        *ngFor="let orgs of form.controls['items']?.controls; let i = index"
        [formGroupName]="i"
      >
        <input formControlName="name" placeholder="Item name" />
        <input formControlName="description" placeholder="Item description" />
        <input formControlName="code" placeholder="Item price" />
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="enable()">
      Enable
    </button>

    </div>
  </form>

  <!-- <p>{{ form.value.items}}</p> -->
</div>
```

The end goal is to enable `formControlName="name/description/code"`

[StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-prepopulate-dynamic-reactive-form-array-5cjchf?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you are successfully enabling "type" but failing to enable name/description/code.

Remember your main FormGroup doesn't contain any name/description/code, it contains an another FormGroup called items, which contains your controls.  First get the sub-form group from the main form, then you have access to the form controls.

Replace enable with this:

```
  enable() {
    this.isOwner = true;
    this.form.get('type').enable({ onlySelf: true });
    let items = this.form.get('items') as FormArray;
    items.controls.forEach(c => {
      c.enable({onlySelf: true});
    })
```